# Using VFP/Neon for a Visual Studio 2008 application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, neon

I'm trying to specify the benchmarks of an ARM Cortex-A8 running Windows Compact 7. I want to compare the performance using the VFP, the NEON and none of them.

I've seen the "-mfpu=xxx" option for GCC compilers but, What are the required compilation settings in Visual Studio 2008 to indicate the FPU used by the application?

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2008 even support ARM ?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 supports neither VFP nor NEON. You should use assembly to make use of those instructions on Windows Mobile/Windows Embedded.

Comment: As Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support VFP/NEON in compilation settings, which compiler should I use to run my standard C/C++ code over VPF/Neon in a Windows Compact 7 application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 supports both VFP and NEON, but since it targets Windows-on-ARM, you cannot compile the whole program with it. Other options might be gcc, and armcc.